# Is there a way to create an SQL query faster than this one?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MySQL table which stores the data of a hotel's reservations. 
I need a query to see the amount of guests who stayed in the hotel for each date.

I was able to create a query (using a subquery) but it performs very slowly. Is there a better way to get the requested data? (For example join the table to itself, or whatever.)

My query is:

```
SELECT CheckOutDate AS Date, 
    (SELECT SUM(NrOfGuests) FROM tblGuests tG 
    WHERE tG.CheckInDate <= tblGuests.CheckOutDate 
    AND tG.CheckOutDate > tblGuests.CheckOutDate 
    AND tG.IsCancelled = False AND tG.NoShow = False) 
AS NrOfGestsStaying 
FROM tblGuests 
GROUP BY CheckOutDate
```

What is the best way to make it perform faster?

Comment: You should check the execution plan. There is not enough information here to properly advise on performance

Comment: Can you do an "Explain Select..." and post the result ?

Comment: I'd try a JOIN instead of a correlated subquery.

Comment: Create index to relational columns

Comment: Explain's result:
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY tblGuests range NULL CheckOutDate 4 NULL 1552 Using index for group-by
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY tG ref CheckInDate,CheckOutDate,NoShow NoShow 2 const 13186 Using where
(sorry for the format, I don't know how to paste it nicer)

Comment: @jarlh: thank you! Could you please let me know the exact query? I was not able to create it.

Comment: @Roy: Thank you! What is considered as a relational column here?

Comment: How many records in the table "tblGuests" with the values of false and true ? index "NoShow" contain only field "NoShow" ?

Comment: @Mike: There are approximately 80,000 records in tblGuests with the values I need. And yes, index "NoShow" contains only one field

Comment: This index is not "selective", drop it. Drop index 'CheckOutDate" and recreate it as composite, contains two fileds (CheckOutDate, CheckInDate)

Comment: Please have the alias on the outer table, not the inner one.

Comment: @RickJames: I've tried, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @DavidP. -- my request was to make the query more readable; it won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original query, the SELECT returns a SUM on every row of the table using a subquery. The duplicates are removed afterwards using a `group by CheckOutDate`. So, in other words, this is the `SUM(NrOfGuests)` for `distinct CheckOutDate`.

You can remove duplicate CheckOutDate in advance by subquerying `distinct CheckOutDate`.  So in the receiving query the SUM is applied just one time for `distinct CheckOutDate`:

```
SELECT dT.CheckOutDate
      ,(SELECT SUM(NrOfGuests) 
          FROM tblGuests tG 
         WHERE tG.CheckInDate <= dT.CheckOutDate 
           AND tG.CheckOutDate >= dT.CheckOutDate
           AND tG.IsCancelled = 0 
           AND tG.NoShow = 0
       ) AS NrOfGuests
  FROM ( 
         SELECT DISTINCT CheckOutDate
           FROM tblGuests
       ) AS dT
  ORDER BY dT.CheckOutDate
```

Comment: `False` is the same as 0.  `'False'` is a 5-character string.

Comment: Also add `INDEX(NoShow, IsCancelled, CheckOutDate)` to help the inner query; add `INDEX(CheckOutDate)` to help the derived table.